# how to sum and group data in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Here's a table that i have:[image]

anyway what I wanted to do in linq is to sum feedGiven column with a group by logdate (we can truncate the time.. it's not needed) with the productionCycleID.

And then take the last 7 Days sum of feed given and average it out.

Currently here's what I got for now:

```
 public IQueryable<FeedingLog> getLastSevenDaysAverage(int intendedProductionCycleID)
    {
        var ListProductionCycleQuery = this.ObjectContext.FeedingLogs.Where(b => b.ProductionCycleID== intendedProductionCycleID);

        var SumResult = from s in ListProductionCycleQuery
                        group s by new {s.ProductionCycleID,s.feedGiven, s.LogDate} into g
                        select new {g.Key.ProductionCycleID, g.Key.LogDate g.Sum(y => y.feedGiven)};

        return ListProductionCycleQuery;
    }
```

I'm seriously stumped by linq, Normally i would do it in sql, but entity framework is a little bit buggy if I go with a view (no primary key issue)

I'm also having this issue in the code :

[image]

basically it says invalid anonymous type member declarator. anonymous type memmer must be declared with a member assignment. 
Thanks in advance for reading and solutions

Comment: Don't group by feedGiven if you want to sum it. Would you do that in SQL? =)

Comment: The production cycle id is always 220, why would you need to group it unless it is variable?

Comment: @thbbft the problem is that list is being filtered to only 220.

Comment: Are the log dates all unique as the example?  That is, is there only one per day?

Comment: it should not be unique. I accidentally made it like that... but it should not be unique

Answer (score 1):

You've included `feedGiven` in the group by, however this is the one field you *don't* want as part of the grouping

```
var SumResult = from s in ListProductionCycleQuery
                group s by new {s.ProductionCycleID,s.LogDate} into g
                select new {g.Key.ProductionCycleID, g.Key.LogDate g.Sum(y => y.feedGiven)};
```

In addition, you're returning the original query from the function, you want to probably define a class to represent the grouped/summed info and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the GroupBy-clause for feedGiven:

```
var SumResult = from s in ListProductionCycleQuery
    group s by new {s.ProductionCycleID,s.LogDate} into g
    select new {g.Key.ProductionCycleID, g.Key.LogDate g.Sum(y => y.feedGiven)};
```